# javascript adding/deleting to/from text file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use jquery, ajax and PHP to add characters to a text file. The POST ajax call returns successful, but the PHP function is not executed. Does anyone see my error? Workaround?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>AjaxSend</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

$(".update_button").click(function() {
    {    
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "changetext.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            alert('You were successful');
            }
        });
    } return false;
});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button class="update_button">Put File</button>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

file_put_contents('test.txt','Text to be added');

?>
```

Comment: It could be related to file permissions. You could try file_put_contents('test.txt','Text to be added') or die('An error occurred'); to see if that is the cause.

Comment: What @Seth said, make sure to alert(html) in the success so you can se the content of changetext.php if an error occur.

Comment: Try to apply `FILE_APPEND` as third parameter to `file_put_contents()`

Answer (score 0):

**1. Check if the file is there, but doesn't get updated**

Try to apply `FILE_APPEND` as third parameter to `file_put_contents()`

**2. Check your permissions.**

Make sure you have write access in the directory you write `test.txt` to. Given your presented code, this would most probably be the root directory in which your PHP script is stored.

**3. Update permissions and pick a directory to write to**

Create a directory (right there where your script `changetext.php` is stored at). Give it any name, for example: `output`

Then set the directory's permissions to 777 and change `changetext.php` to this:

```
file_put_contents('output/test.txt','Text to be added', FILE_APPEND);
```